# Lost all my sharing stats by purchasing a domain

Tags: wordpress, facebook, statistics

I lost all the likes on my website on Wordpress then I bought the domain. It turns out that is the same site, but now no longer use the wordpress.com but .com (http://sobreasdeliciasdavida.com/).

Despite recent, my blog already had good statistics and the loss of more than 500 shares in Facebook brings my blog back to its beginning.

Can you offer the option of importing the likes to the new domain since the posts are the same?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it the nature of sharing, that, if you change your domain, that all references doesn't belong to your new domain name? wordpress.com != sobreasdeliciasdavida.com. I have to gues, but i would say, that you have to start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes when you move a well-established site, you'll want to set up a 301 redirect from the previous site. It's a permanent redirect that ensures that people following links to your previous site end up at your new one. I should point out, though, that your blog is far from taken back to its beginning. Remember, *content is king*, and you now have a site that's totally under your control and is already packed with great content, content that you know people respond to, like in social media venues, comment on, etc., etc. Don't worry about the 500 you might not get back because you certainly have thousands more on the way if you just keep doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly using the facebook code in your website, then you can check this out. http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2172926/maintain-social-shares-site-migration